# Why does this requests spec fail intermittently, or how can I debug it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot, rspec-rails

This is the test that fails intermittently:

```
  context "as a regular_user" do
    before :each do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :role => 'regular_user')
      visit new_user_session_path unless current_path == new_user_session_path
      fill_in "Email", :with => @user.email
      fill_in "Password", :with => @user.password
      click_button "Sign In"
    end

    it "removes thing from favorites while on thing index page" do
      @things = FactoryGirl.create_list(:thing, 5)
      @user.set_mark :favorite, @things.first
      @user.reload.favorite_things
      visit things_path unless current_path == things_path
      expect{
        first(:link, "Remove from favorites").click # Sometimes this fails
        @user.reload.favorite_things
      }.to change { @user.favorite_things.count }.by(-1)
      page.should have_content("Sort by")
    end
  end
```

I'm using the gem [markable](https://rubygems.org/gems/markable) to provide the favorites feature.

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the success/failure when I run the specs with `rspec` (it's not like once it fails it always fails, or vice versa). There might be a pattern when the specs are run through `guard` (`spork` is also being used) in that if I start `guard` and the test passes then it will always pass while that instance of `guard` is running ... Sames goes for failures - if I start `guard` and it fails, then all subsequent runs within that instance of `guard` will also fail.

Just now I ran `rspec spec/requests/users_spec.rb:148` to run that one spec, and it failed:

```
1) Users as a regular_user removes thing from favorites while on thing index page
     Failure/Error: click_link "Remove from favorites" # Sometimes this fails
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "Remove from favorites"
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:155:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:153:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I ran `rspec spec/requests/users_spec.rb:148` again right after that, and it succeeded:

```
Finished in 0.83754 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

I've tried adding "asdfasdf" within the `<% @things.each do |thing| %>` section of the `index.html.erb` view file, and checking for that with `page.should have_content("asdfasdf")` and this fails sometimes. I tried adding `page.should have_selector('.favoritesblock', visible: true)` just before the `expect` block (`favoritesblock` exists within the same `@things` block in the view), and this fails sometimes. It never fails to find text outside of the `<% @things.each do |thing| %>` loop, however.

I added `save_and_open_page` just before the `first(:link, "Remove from favorites").click # Sometimes this fails` line, and was able to produce an instance where the spec failed. The page only contained two things (my `FactoryGirl` call should be creating 5) and neither of them had a 'Remove from favorites' link (depending on if the thing is favorited or not, it displays "Add to favorites" or "Remove from favorites").

Based on that, I tried modifying the first two lines of the spec a bit, but it didn't help (still fails sometimes):

```
5.times { FactoryGirl.create(:thing) }
@user.set_mark :favorite, Thing.first
```

What I did notice is that when it succeeds, it does display the 'Remove from favorites' link for the first thing but it doesn't always display all 5 things.

So, I need to know why this spec fails intermittently or what else I can do to figure out what's causing the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your factory for Thing? Also any constraints on the model - maybe sometimes the Things are failing to be created?

Comment: YES! Thank you! The problem was that I've got a field, `active`, which I set in my factory as `f.active { [true, false].sample }`. So, sometimes it would make an active thing & sometimes it would make an inactive thing. Whenever the test made the first thing inactive, the spec would have nothing to mark as favorite. My fix is to change my spec to `@things = FactoryGirl.create_list(:thing, 5, :active => true)` so that it only creates active things for this spec.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted :) I've had to deal with similar problems using Fabricator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I set up my Factory is the cause of the intermittent rspec failures.

The item has a boolean field, `active`, which either displays the thing on the site (if it's `true`) or does not display the thing on the site (if it's `false`).

I was clever with my Factory, and set that field as `f.active { [true, false].sample }`. So, sometimes the Factory creates active things and sometimes it creates inactive things. I purposefully created my Factories to behave this way because I want the default Factory to create as wide a selection of possible real-world things as possible. I just need to keep in mind that some aspects need to be manually set sometimes - like in this case, I need to create only active things.

The fix is to change my spec to only create active things:

```
@things = FactoryGirl.create_list(:thing, 5, :active => true)
```

Comment: I just had this issue with my User factory:                      `factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@burningpony.com" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}@burningpony.com" }`. Thanks so much!